# Data Value Changing in Swift Playground

Tags: swift, nsdata, foundation

In a playground, the following code initializes Data using an UnsafeBufferPointer, as described in the [Apple Foundation Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779609-init)

```
let data = Data()
let test = Array(0..<10)
let pointer = UnsafeRawPointer(test).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
data = Data.init(buffer: UnsafeBufferPointer(start: pointer, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: test)))
data[8]
```

Running this program multiple times produces different values for data[8]. Why is the value changing?

Comment: Is this the exact code? `data` is a constant so you can't reassign it here: `data = Data.init(...)`

Comment: Yeah, it's the exact code. Prior to Swift 3 the reason was because the let only referred to the reference to the data, not the data itself. However, after Swift 3, Foundation classes were bridged to Swift structs. So I don't know why it works, but it still does.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the information on MemoryLayout. I really don't know what the expected behavior is. Ideally, the code would correspond to a number in the array (I think). I'm trying to learn more about the Foundation Framework, and to that end, have been making Playgrounds that use every part of the API for each Foundation class. I've made it to Data, was going through the initializers, got to this one, and am now at a loss. If you know how / why someone would use this initializer, or just know of a good guide to UnsafePointer, UnsafeBuffer, etc. I would be very appreciative.

Comment: @BrandonBradley Figured I might as well dump my comments into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: test)` is equivalent to `MemoryLayout<[Int]>.size` (the parameter is only used as a way to infer the generic placeholder type). It's not giving you the size of the array's buffer, it's giving you the size of the `Array` struct *itself*, which is currently 1 word (8 bytes on a 64-bit machine) in size, as the elements are held indirectly.

Therefore the `Data` instance you construct only holds 8 bytes, so accessing `data[8]` will read out of bounds garbage; which is why you're getting unexpected results. This out of bounds access will actually [cause a runtime error in Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/d31ffc7d5e3794e022f03828ffb05621d4c94ad3) (as of the version that ships with Xcode 9 beta 4).

But ignoring all of that, using `UnsafeRawPointer(test)` to begin with is *undefined behaviour*, as it's using a pointer to a buffer that's only valid for the duration of the initialiser call. Swift only guarantees that auto-generated pointer arguments (e.g when passing an array to a constant pointer parameter) will be valid for the duration of the given function call (see the Swift team's blog post on [Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6)).

If you just want to dump the bytes of the array's buffer into a `Data` instance, you simply want:

```
let test = Array(0 ..< 10)
let data = test.withUnsafeBufferPointer(Data.init)
// or let data = test.withUnsafeBufferPointer { Data(buffer: $0) }

print(data as NSData) // bridge to NSData to get a full print-out of bytes  

// <00000000 00000000
//  01000000 00000000
//  02000000 00000000
//  03000000 00000000
//  04000000 00000000
//  05000000 00000000
//  06000000 00000000
//  07000000 00000000
//  08000000 00000000
//  09000000 00000000>

print(data[8]) // 1
```

<sup>(64-bit little endian machine)</sup>

which uses [`withUnsafeBufferPointer(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1540400-withunsafebufferpointer) to get an immutable buffer pointer view onto the array's buffer (and if it's not native, e.g wrapping an `NSArray`; it will have to be created), and `Data`'s [`init(buffer:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/1779609-init) to construct a new instance with the bytes from the given buffer pointer.

If you want the bytes to correspond 1 : 1 to the elements in the array, you need to make each of the elements 1 byte in length.

For example, by starting with a `[UInt8]`:

```
let test = [UInt8](0 ..< 10)
let data = test.withUnsafeBufferPointer(Data.init)
print(data as NSData) // <00010203 04050607 0809>
print(data[8]) // 8
```

And because you're now working with a sequence of `UInt8`, you can actually simplify the initialisation slightly by using `Data`'s [sequence of `UInt8` initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/data/2852972-init):

```
let data = Data(test)
```

Comment: Seriously, thank you. Finding well explained, up to date, information on Data (and a lot of other Foundation classes, actually) is nigh impossible, so this was extremely helpful.

Comment: @BrandonBradley Happy to help :)